# displaying content of Object of someother class, Acessing webservice object

Tags: java, web-services, object, xml-rpc, bugzilla

How do I access a object of some other class through my class??
I tried toString but it can display contents only of its own object not other class objects.

Basically, I am able to access Bugzilla Webservice API through java code(xmlrpc) and in return i get a object of **`class java.util.HashMap.`**
But i am unable to understand how to access the object returned.

```
    Object createResult = rpcClient.execute("Bug.search", new Object[]{bugMap});
```

how do i get bugs information from : "createResult" object.ie, contents of cretaeResult object.According to Bugzilla documentation **two items are returned**, bugs and faults, both are **array of hashes**. and i want to access these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Case someone else needs this.
Object from Bugzilla is first typecasted to a HashMap type. Each Keyset of HashMap itself is an object that contains the array of an object where in each object is again a Hashmap. Quite Complex.

```
HashMap bugs = (HashMap)bugzillaObject; 
for( Object key : bugs.keySet() )
{

    Object value = bugs.get( key );
    Object[] valueArray = (Object[])value;
    for( Object v : valueArray )
    {

        HashMap L = (HashMap)v;
        for( Object key1 : L.keySet() )
        System.out.println( "Key " + "= "+key1  + ", value " + "= "+ L.get(key1) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it returns a HashMap, then you want to make the variable "createResult" a HashMap.  ie,

```
HashMap createResult = rpcClient.execute("Bug.search", new Object[]{bugMap});
```

Then "createResult" is a HashMap, and you can use it as such, eg
createResult.isEmpty()
createResult.size()
etc

Good luck!